# Dropzone.js rename file after upload base on response

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm trying to figure out a way how to rename file after upload using dropzone.js so I could later delete it just by sending correct name.

What I have right now:

```
this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
   console.log(responseText); // responseText contains actual file name after server modifications
});

addRemoveLinks: true,
        this.on("removedfile", function(file) {
          var name = file.name;
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'delete_file.html',
            data: {
              'file-name': name,
            },
          });
        });
```

As you can see in my ajax data I am sending initial file name, not the one that is actually on the server (e.g. if there are multiple same named files server will rename them).
I have been thinking of changing previewElement name on success:

```
file.previewElement.querySelector(".name").textContent = responseText;
```

and then refer to this in ajax, but it doesn't look like an elegant approach.

Other alternative would be to create a map with <file, new_name> mapping, but I'm not sure if that's not an overkill.

How would you recommend accessing new file name after upload?

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest option I came up with is using `file.xhr.response` value which hold the new name instead of `file.name`